# How to add two enums to a single Map object as key and value

Tags: java, enums

I have two enums. I would like to create a Map object out of the two enums.

I have gone through EnumMap but it says only the key can be an enum. Please correct me if i am wrong.

```
private enum Export {
    BINGOEXPORT, DEFECTSEXPORT, IBC3EXPORT, IBCONTRACTSEXPORT, 
    RMAHEADEREXPORT, RMALINESEXPORT, SITESEXPORT, SREXPORT
};

private enum Preperation {
    BINGOPREPERATION, DEFECTSPREPERATION, IBC3PREPERATION, 
    IBCONTRACTSPREPERATION, RMAHEADERPREPERATION, RMALINESPREPERATION, 
    SITESPREPERATION, SRPREPERATION, IBEXPORTLOGPREPERATION
};
```

Comment: You could do a interface which will be implemented by both enums, with common methos like `toString`,... Then the map would be as this interface type `Map<InterfaceEnum, String>`.... So you would be able to use thise common methods.

Comment: Could you please show code that displays the message that only the key can be an `enum` in `EnumMap`? Making both key and value an `enum` compiles perfectly fine: `EnumMap<Export,Preparation> e2p = new EnumMap<Export,Preparation>(Export.class);` ([demo](http://ideone.com/BaQojz))

Comment: “EnumMap … says only the key can be an enum.”  Not correct.  The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) uses `V` to represent the values type.  Not “V extends Enum.”  Not V extends anything.  V can be any type, including enum values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal HashMap works fine to have the enum as a key and value.

```
Map<Export, Preparation> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(Export.BINGOEXPORT, Preparation.BINGOPREPERATION);
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the OP that says they need to have both classes as a Key. The only detail provided is that they needed both the key and value to be an enum. @angularBeginner, would you clarify please?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I disagree. The title says *"add two enums to a single Map object as key **and** value"*, and the question text says *"EnumMap says only the key can be an enum"*, i.e. OP apparently thinks the *value* cannot be an enum. So, unless you interpret all that as a request for a bidirectional map, i.e. both the key and the value can be both enums (`Map<Export|Preperation, Preperation|Export>`), this is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use one `enum` as the key and the other one as a value, `EnumMap` allows you to do that ([demo](http://ideone.com/BaQojz)):

```
EnumMap<Export,Preparation> e2p = new EnumMap<Export,Preparation>(Export.class);
e2p.put(Export.RMALINESEXPORT, Preparation.SRPREPERATION);
System.out.println(e2p.get(Export.RMALINESEXPORT));
```

If you would like to mix `enum`s as keys of the same `Map`, one approach is to make a common interface for the two `enum`s, and use it as the key type for your `Map`. You can do it because Java `enum`s are allowed to extend classes and implement interfaces:

```
private interface CommonKey {
    int hashCode();
    boolean equals(Object other);
}

private enum Export implements CommonKey {
    BINGOEXPORT, DEFECTSEXPORT, IBC3EXPORT, IBCONTRACTSEXPORT, RMAHEADEREXPORT, RMALINESEXPORT, SITESEXPORT, SREXPORT
}

private enum Preperation implements CommonKey {
    BINGOPREPERATION, DEFECTSPREPERATION, IBC3PREPERATION, IBCONTRACTSPREPERATION, RMAHEADERPREPERATION, RMALINESPREPERATION, SITESPREPERATION, SRPREPERATION, IBEXPORTLOGPREPERATION
}
```

Now you can declare your map:

```
Map<CommonKey,SomeClass> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put(Export.BINGOEXPORT, someObject);
myMap.put(Preperation.RMAHEADERPREPERATION, antherObject);
```

Both interface methods are optional, because they are inherited from `java.lang.Object`. I added them to the interface anyway, to make it easier for your readers to understand what parts of the implementing classes are important for your use of the interface.

Comment: Do you actually need `hashCode` and `equals` on the interface?

Comment: @weston No, you don't need them, because they are available on the `java.lang.Object`. However, it's a good idea to add them anyway to avoid "marker interfaces" and to highlight the parts of the class that you actually planning to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making two enums which implement the same interface